# GitHub Actions doesn't seem to recognize my .env secrets

Tags: github-actions, playwright, dotenv

I've got a Playwright project and I'm trying to use a `.env` file along with GitHub secrets for authentication.

My `.env`:

```
USERNAME={redacted}
PASSWORD={redacted}
```

In the tests themselves (which are passing locally), I'm using the `process.env.{variable}!` syntax for TypeScript:

```js
test.describe.serial('Dashboard', () => {
  test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto('/');
    await page.getByPlaceholder('Email').fill(process.env.USERNAME!);
    await page.getByPlaceholder('Password').fill(process.env.PASSWORD!);
```

In GitHub, I've set up the same variables as repository secrets. Here is my `playwright.yml` file:

```yaml
name: Playwright Tests
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main, master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main, master ]
jobs:
  test:
    timeout-minutes: 60
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: 18
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm ci
    - name: Install Playwright Browsers
      run: npx playwright install --with-deps
    - name: Run Playwright tests
      run: npx playwright test
      env:
        USERNAME: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
        PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      if: always()
      with:
        name: playwright-report
        path: playwright-report/
        retention-days: 30
```

When the tests are run in GH, it *appears* that the secrets are being accessed correctly, but the tests will inevitably fail when they get to the first assertion:

```
Run npx playwright test
  npx playwright test
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    USERNAME: ***
    PASSWORD: ***

...
**.spec.ts:16:7 › *** › create a new *** ────

    Test timeout of 30000ms exceeded while running "beforeEach" hook.

      3 |
      4 | test.describe.serial('Stress testing UI', () => {  
    > 5 |   test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
        |        ^
      6 |     await page.goto('/');
      7 |     await page.getByPlaceholder('Email').fill(process.env.USERNAME!);
      8 |     await page.getByPlaceholder('Password').fill(process.env.PASSWORD!);

        at /home/runner/work/{redacted}/{redacted}/tests/***.spec.ts:5:8

    Error: locator.click: Page closed
    =========================== logs ===========================
    waiting for getByRole('link', { name: '{redacted}' })
    ============================================================

       8 |     await page.getByPlaceholder('Password').fill(process.env.PASSWORD!);
       9 |     await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign in' }).click();
    > 10 |     await page.getByRole('link', { name: '{redacted}' }).click();
```

What am I doing wrong?

What I've done and what I expect:
I've written Playwright tests that pass locally but fail when run in GH. It appears that GH secrets are being passed in an UNDEFINED or the like.

I expect my application to authenticate successfully in the cloud as it does locally.

Comment: It's not clear what makes you think that outcome is related to the environment variables not getting set. Also your `.env` doesn't matter when you're setting actual env vars.

Comment: @jonrsharpe looking at the output of the tests, the runner appears to be entering something in the username and password fields, and clicking sign in. However, in every case, the validations after clicking the login button are failing. I have a handful of tests that ensure `/sign_in` is no longer present in the URL after successfully signing in -- those are all failing consistently. This tells me that the runner is trying to enter something in the login fields, and clicking sign_in, but authentication is failing. And given that these tests are passing locally, it must be access to secrets.

Comment: The error seems to be pointing to `await page.getByRole('link', { name: '{redacted}' }).click();`, which is only executed after the username and password are filled. If you really want to prove to yourself that the username and password are not being entered correctly, base64 encode the username and password and display that in your workflow. Copy the encoded values (which should be visible), and base64 decode them. If they are not the same as what you initially entered, then you can confidently claim that GH actions is the culprit.